# Set textbox to required when radio is checked

Tags: jquery

Having issues setting a textbox to "required" when a radio button is selected.

```
function tempcheck(){
    $("#mytext").prop('required',true);
  }
```

html

```
<input type="radio" name="myradio" id="myradio" onclick="tempcheck()" />

<input name="mytext" type="text" id="mytext" />
```

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/sde2nmhh/1/

Comment: Do you see any errors on your browser developer console?

Comment: I'd use `onchange` instead of `onclick`. It's possible to change the value without actually clicking on it.

Comment: Yea I am getting tempcheck is undefined. not sure why

Comment: Voting to close, as we are unable to reproduce the problem with the code you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#mytext").attr('required',true);
```

I think in W3C they mention that the required is attributes

Comment: jQuery automatically translates

Comment: it does, I tried both and it still doesn't work properly